# Implement exponential function via LUT

Tags: python, math, fpga, exp

I have implemented the exponential function with a LUT and the obtained results seems be right. The way that I'm performed this has been using the *Intermediate value theorem* and the properties of powers. But for example: if the input value is `x=5.25`, this is equal to:

[image]

So, my questions are:

1. <strike>If the value to calculate is greater than one, is needed a new LUT to calculate the integer part?</strike> ***Already answered below***
2. What would be the optimal way from the point of view of hardware resources to implement the exponential? In this point, I don't asking about fixed or float point.

Here is the exponential function that I have implement with a LUT and the obtained results to compare with the real exponential function:

```
e_constant = 2.718281828459045235360
depth = 16
idx = 1/(2**np.arange(1,depth+1))
LUT_p = np.exp(1/(2**np.arange(1,depth+1)))
LUT_n = np.exp(-1/(2**np.arange(1,depth+1)))
def EXP_LUT(x):
    acc = 0 # Accumulator
    exp = 1 # Returned value
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    if x == 1:
        return e_constant
    
    for i in range(depth):    
        if acc < x:
            acc = acc + idx[i]
            exp = exp * LUT_p[i]
        elif acc > x:
            acc = acc - idx[i]
            exp = exp * LUT_n[i]
        else:
            break
    return exp
```

[image]

## Edit 1

***In order to answer about my first question: if the value to calculate is greater than one, is needed a new LUT to calculate the integer part?***

A very logical solution is change the maximun value of the LUT's.
For example:

```
# This works great to ranges between -1 and 1
LUT_i = 1/(2**np.arange(1,depth+1))
LUT_p = np.exp(LUT_i)
LUT_n = np.exp(-LUT_i)

# This works great to ranges between -8 and 8
LUT_i = 8/(2**np.arange(1,depth+1))
LUT_p = np.exp(LUT_i)
LUT_n = np.exp(-LUT_i)
```

The problem here is the accuracy loss in the approximation, to solve this (only if really was neccesary) the solution is create a LUT with more values. Instead of 16, set to 32 stored values. The following graphs demostrates this:

[image]

[image]

It's clear that the graphs with the approximation error for 32 stored values is less than with 16 stored values.
So, I think the first question is already answered.